# Is there a Jira notifications page?

Tags: jira

Is there a way to view all my notifications on a single page in Jira instead of a small popover in Confluence, preferably with a filter to only show unread notifications?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: @music2myear I've searched the first page results of Google but found no solution. Turns out the notifications for Jira weren't even in Jira itself, but Confluence, which also didn't have a notification page i could find.

Comment: So, please update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Jira does not have a page for notifications. The best option is to use a filter in your mailbox.